# Computing the accuracy of an answer

Tags: likelihood, accuracy, reliability

Let's assume I have three experts providing an answer.

- Expert 1 is 95% accurate (The likelihood of providing a correct answer is 95%).
- Expert 2 is 90% accurate
- Expert 3 is 85% accurate

They are answering a question with two possible answers: TRUE or FALSE.

If Expert 1 answers the question alone, I know that their answer is 95% accurate.

What would be the accuracy of the answer if all 3 experts answer the question the same way? I would expect the accuracy of the answer to be greater than 95% but I'm not sure how to calculate it.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Svpino, welcome to the site. You're using reliable in a slightly strange way - I think you should use the word accuracy.

Comment: You are right. Let me fix the question.

Comment: No definite answer is possible without information about how the experts respond jointly.  They could answer all questions the same way anywhere from 70% to 90% of the time.  If it were more than 90% of the time, then expert 3 would be agreeing with expert 1 more than 90% of the time and therefore would be correct more than 85% of the time.

Comment: Hey whuber, I'm not sure I understand your comment. What I'd like to know if the accuracy of the answer if ALL experts give the same answer.

Comment: At the very least, the accuracy cannot possibly increase!

Answer (score -1):

As said Whuber, the answer depends on the dependence between the 3 experts.

If you assume that each expert answer is not dependent (in the statistical sense of the term) of the other experts then the answer will be right in $(1-(0.05*0.1*0.15))*100= 99.925\%$ of the cases.

Comment: Yup, this makes sense. The answers from the experts are independent.

Comment: It isn't possible for experts 2 and 3 always to agree with expert 1, for otherwise experts 2 and 3 would be correct more often than they are assumed to be.  Your calculation is incorrect, because it is obvious that all three experts cannot simultaneously be correct more often than the least accurate of them all, which is 85%.  When the experts are independent, then they are correct only $0.85\times0.90\times0.95=72.675\%$ of the time.

Comment: I agree with the first point, it was only to illustrate a case of dependence that I wrote that, I agree that it is misleading and I edited the answer to remove it. I disagree with your second point: The author asks for the probability that the answer is right given(!) that the 3 answers are the same while your answer of 72.675% corresponds to the probability that the three experts all give the right answer. My answer do responds to the initial question which is about conditional probabilities under the assumption of independence.

Comment: Your calculation appears to produce the probability that not all experts give the *wrong* answer.  That is not the same as the event that they all give the right answer.

Comment: Since the question states that the three experts give the same answer, then either all experts are wrong or all experts are right, isn't it? The two events are complementary.

Comment: Definitely not: it's possible for two to be wrong and one right or one wrong and two right.  Assuming independence doesn't just mean these are possible: it implies they both have positive probability.

Comment: "All experts answer the (same) question the same way", so the answers will either be TRUE TRUE TRUE or FALSE FALSE FALSE... Since they answer to the same question how can your last message be true? I mean I'm not a quantum physicist but...

Comment: Fair enough: now you're on the right track.  The original question invites you to compute a conditional probability.  You have performed part of the calculation, but the number you provide is not the answer.